# What's taking CPU time in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a complex Google Sheet, and the gray bar on the top right takes a long time to complete. Is there a way to see what the sheet is calculating to pinpoint down what part of the sheet is taking up the CPU time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no CPU profiler provided by Sheets. The following may help locate the issue:

1. Make a copy of the spreadsheet
2. "Freeze" some of its calculated values (select a range, press Ctrl-C, then Ctrl-Shift-V, overwriting formulas with static values).
3. Observe the effect on the performance of the spreadsheet.
4. Repeat for a different group of formulas.