# Can't open version history of my public Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that is editable by anyone who has the URL. When I go to File->Version history->See version history, after a few seconds I get the following error:

> Version history unavailable
>
> Google Docs could not display the version history because of a server
>   error or a problem with the network connection. Please try again later.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Tried with different browsers on different computers to no avail.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove sheets, columns, rows that aren no longer required.

Try using a computer with higher resources (CPU, RAM, Internet speed, ...)

Also, report this problem to Google by using Google Feedback and also to the official help forum were Google Product Experts could escalate the problem to an specialist.

Regarding Google Feedback

In Google Sheets,

1. Open the problematic spreadsheet
2. Click **Help**, then click **Report a problem**
3. Fill up the report form and submit it.

Related

- [Where does the calculation take place?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/75449/88163)
- [CPU vs. RAM for Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104865/88163)

Comment: Thanks, I already reported the problem in the help menu. The product forum already has at least two topics with the same issue without any resolution (at least it did not help me). But whatever I can try posting there.